# dockerfile variables values are not passing to container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile as shown below which is appending some lines in org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg file

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV  DB_SERVER            1.1.1.1
ENV  DB_SCHEMA            mydb
ENV  DB_USER              myuser
ENV  DB_PASSWORD          mypass

RUN /bin/echo $'log4j.appender.DB.URL = jdbc:mysql://$DB_SERVER/$DB_SCHEMA\n\
log4j.appender.DB.user = $DB_USER\n\
log4j.appender.DB.password = $DB_PASSWORD\n'\ 
>> $KARAF_HOME/etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg
```

I am expecting that above entries suppose to be appended in a file with values but echo is just appending as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of single quotes is stopping the environment variables from being interpolated. Use double quotes along with the `-e` flag to `echo` (stops it treating newlines as literals).

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV  DB_SERVER            1.1.1.1
ENV  DB_SCHEMA            mydb
ENV  DB_USER              myuser
ENV  DB_PASSWORD          mypass

RUN /bin/echo -e "log4j.appender.DB.URL = jdbc:mysql://$DB_SERVER/$DB_SCHEMA\n\
log4j.appender.DB.user = $DB_USER\n\
log4j.appender.DB.password = $DB_PASSWORD\n"\
>> $KARAF_HOME/etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg
```

That works perfectly for me. I can then do a `RUN cat $KARAF_HOME/etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg` and a `CMD cat $KARAF_HOME/etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg` in the Dockerfile and it shows the below output for both (at build then run time respectively):

```
log4j.appender.DB.URL = jdbc:mysql://1.1.1.1/mydb
log4j.appender.DB.user = myuser
log4j.appender.DB.password = mypass
```

Comment: It's not recommended to use ENV because it'll be accessible by any container and it's not a good practice that all containers will have DB_PASSWORD. It's a security issue. So, unless for password, ARG should be used, not ENV.

Comment: Sure, but that's got nothing to do with the question :p

Answer (score 1):

- ENV are accessible in image **build-time** and **run-time** by the *ENTRYPOINT*.
- ARG are accessible in image **build-time** but not in container starting (run-time).

So, if you want to access in your Dockerfile and your command is not an entrypoint, you should define them as ARG:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ARG  DB_SERVER=1.1.1.1
ARG  DB_SCHEMA=mydb
ARG  DB_USER=myuser
ARG  DB_PASSWORD=mypass

RUN /bin/echo $'log4j.appender.DB.URL = jdbc:mysql://${DB_SERVER}/${DB_SCHEMA}\n\
log4j.appender.DB.user = ${DB_USER}\n\
log4j.appender.DB.password = ${DB_PASSWORD}\n'\ 
>> ${BPPM_HOME}/etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg
```

Comment: You can access `ENV` in any command you like, including `RUN`.

Comment: That's what I told, or what I tried, both are valid in **built-time** but more recommended ARG.

Comment: @mulg0r for ARG it throwing error "Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 6: ARG requires exactly one argument".  by provide = between variable and value solve it. but still have to follow johnharris85 to make it work

Comment: You're right, sorry, I forgot it. I'll edit. Anyway, be careful with ENV that DB_PASSWORD will be accessible in containers, not only in build. So, ARG is more recommended